# Chrome window blinks after switchTo with webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm currently testing an application with multiple 'Chrome tabs' with Selenium & chromedriver in Java.

The goal I want to achieve is to switch between tabs.

For that, no problem I use:

```
driver.switchTo().window("CDwindow-***************");
```

It works fine. But I have some pages where I'm facing to an issue. Those pages are simple, they **listen to an event `TestLoad`**, and do something:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset=utf-8 />
    <title>test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
document.addEventListener('TestLoad', onTestLoad, false);
function onTestLoad(event) {
    alert('TestLoad event');
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

When the page loads, my application **inject** some Javascript in the page:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var evt = document.createEvent("Event");
    evt.initEvent("TestLoad", true, true);
    setTimeout(function(){document.dispatchEvent(evt)}, 1);
});
```

Now when I switch to this kind of page, and try to ask for something through the webdriver, as `dirver.getTitle()`, **the page 'blinks'** ! It does not reload the page but in case of the page contains animations, it will reset them. It seems that it reload the tab instance.

The simple way to reproduce is to manually open the chrome dev tool before get the title, it will close it.

Do you have any idea why I get this behavior ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you manage to find solution to your problem? I am experiencing the same thing only using webdriverIO switchWindow method :(